# Populating an asp:Image with an image selected within an asp:FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

With using an asp FileUpload control, is there anyway i can have an asp Image populated with the image as soon as i select one within the FileUpload control without uploading it to a folder etc, just populate the asp Image control with the image selected.

Comment: It is possible to do with HTML 5 using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), but this requires Google Chrome / IE10 (Not sure what Firefox version supports this). What versions of browser do you need to support with this?

Comment: Well, you could store the image in a session and then serve images from the session using some other page, but that's about it, I'm affraid. The ASP.NET `Image` control only has an image URL, you can't directly assign the image to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it directly on the Client Side : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/e52Tg/)

```
var input = document.getElementById('fileUp');
var img = document.getElementById('img1');

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        img.src =  e.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

There are a few issues with this approach.

> 1. The Img's source will not be stored retained on Postback, you can
>      create a workaround for this but it's a little indepth.
> 2. The use of this requires support for the [HTML5 Web FileReader
>      API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).
>      Which is only supported by a limited amount of browsers (See full
>      support list at the bottom of the link I posted)

If you only require this for client-side processing and only for IE10 / Chrome / Other supported browsers then you'll be fine. **Otherwise this approach will not work for you.**

Answer (score 1):

Store the image binary in a Session may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly but here is a neat way to do it without saving in your proper destination folder.

Taken from http://forums.asp.net/p/962719/1197308.aspx

> for security reasons the FileUpload control doesn't allow you to
>   pre-load the file. However you can have a temporary directory(e.g.
>   preloaddirectory) for files before placing it in the production
>   directroy (e.g. uploadedDirectory). After you saved your file to that
>   temp directory, you can use FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream
>   to get the content of the posted file into a byte array. From there
>   you can do:
>
> C#:
>
> byte[] buff ; buff = (byte[])FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputSream;
>   Response.ContentType = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType;
>   Response.BinaryWrite (buff);
>
> VB.NET dim buff as byte()
>
> buff = Ctype(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream, byte())
>   Response.ContentType = FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType
>   Response.BinaryWrite (buff) ...
>
> this will return the image as a stream of bytes w/c will be
>   interpreted by the browser(assuming you have the correct content type)
>   to be your image and will display accordingly

Comment: It is possible to do directly, however it requires HTML5 FileReader API support, which limits the cross-browser capability. And also it may will not keep after postback.